# Disprove that this subset of P3 is not a subspace by using a counterexample

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

The set of all polynomials with degree 3 plus the zero polynomial.
A hint would be appreciated to get me going :)

Comment: $(x^3 + x^2) - x^3 = ?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $V$ be the subset of $P_3$ consisting of all polynomials of degree three and the zero polynomial. Note that $x^3+1,-x^3\in V$ while
$$
x^3+1+(-x^3)=1\notin V
$$
Hence $V$ is not a subspace.